# Сравнение русскоязычных строк

Tags: c++

Необходимо сравнить русскоязычные строки. Одна уже записана вначале работы, а 2-ая в процессе выполнения вводится с клавиатуры. Проблема: вторая строка читается как аброкадабра, поэтому некорректно сравнивается с первой. Код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
void compare();
void compare(char*w,char*t)//функция сравнения строк
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,".1251");
    cout<<"Your translation:"<<' ';
    cin.getline(t,20);//ввод строки с клавиатуры
    cout<<t<<endl;//вывод введённой строки
    if(strcmp(t,w)==0)
        cout<<"true\n"<<w<<endl;
    if(strcmp(t,w)!=0)
        cout<<"false\n"<<w<<endl;
}
void main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,".1251");
    char*word={"task\n"};//нужно написать перевод этого слова на русский язык
    char*r_t={"задание"};//строка с которой сравнивают
    cout<<word;
    char*trans;
    trans=new char[20];
    compare(r_t,trans);//сравнение
}
```

Результат:

> `task
> Your translation:задание
> //здесь появилась аброкадабра
> false
> задание`

Answer (score 2):

Напишите, какая ОС.

Видимо, Windows и ввод с консоли. В этом случае константа в программе скорее всего в кодировке cp-1251 (она же ANSI), а символы вводимые с клавиатуры в cp866.

Возможно этот пример будет Вам полезен.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

static char *
linget (char *str)
{
  char *p;

  printf("> "); fflush(stdout);
  if (p = fgets(str,1024,stdin))
    str[strlen(str)-1] = 0;
  return p;
}

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char buf[1024],buf1[1024];
  char out866 = isatty(fileno(stdout)),
    in866 = isatty(fileno(stdin));

  char *hello = "Привет !";
  if (out866 )
    CharToOem(hello,buf);  // AnsiToOem(hello,buf); синонимы
  else
    strcpy(buf,hello);
  printf ("%s\n",buf);

  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < ac; i++) {
    if (out866)
      AnsiToOem(av[i],buf); //     CharToOem(av[i],buf);  синонимы
    else
      strcpy(buf,av[i]);
    printf ("arg[%d] : %s\n",i,buf);
  }

  printf ("Enter lines for strstr() with \"%s\"\n",buf);
  while (linget(buf1)) {
    if (in866)
      OemToChar(buf1,buf);  // OemToAnsi(buf1,buf);  синонимы
    else
      strcpy(buf,buf1);
    printf ("result of strstr() : %s\n",
        strstr(hello,buf) == NULL? "No":"Yes");
  }

  printf ("End\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

OC: Windows 7 x86 64-bit  компилятор:  gcc.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)

Небольшое пояснение: в консоли Винды ввод (stdin) производится в cp866, **ОДНАКО (!) передаваемые в программу аргументы** из интерпретатора команд CMD.EXE преобразуются в кодировку cp1251, которая применяется в файловой системе (и для имен файлов и для русских букв в тексте файла).

С той же целью в примере применяется функция isatty(), позволяющая различить в программе что (файл или терминал (консоль)) ассоциировано с потоком ввода/вывода.

Comment: Неужели в винде такие извращения?

Comment: именно такие ^^

Comment: Более того, если Винда **не русская**, то русские буквы будут в UTF-16 (2 байта на русскую букву).

Comment: Linux, I love you

Comment: это точно ^^

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил Вашу программу в Ubuntu 11.04 g++-4.5.2, и все работает как надо. Наверное, что-то в локализации Вашей системы

Comment: Скорее всего извечная тема кодировок :)

Comment: Ну да. Писать консольные проги для вин - это что-то.

Comment: когда ТС пишет "аброкадабра" это уже о чем-то говорит :)

Comment: Да я уже на безграмотность внимание не обращаю...